# List of certain user flagged nodes in a view

Tags: views, flags

I'm using Drupal 6.28 latest views and flag modules (for drupal 6 ofc). I have a node content type "group" which can be flagged. So I'm user with id2 I'll go on node/10 and flag it, then I'll go on node/11 also flag it. Now I want to display all flagged nodes by me on my user page /users/myname.

What I did so far:

1 Created a node view
2 Set up a relationship **Flags: User's flagged content**, checked **Include only users who have flagged content.** then chosen my created flag. (for content type "group")
3 added argument **Flags: user uid**
4 added field "title"

I have 2 flagged nodes but it shows nothing.. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Create a Node View

2) Add a relationship Flags: Node flag (select the required flags and tick "Include only tagged Nodes"

3) Add another Relationship Flags : User (use the above relationship on this)

4) Add Argument User ID (*named Contextual Filters in Drupal 7*) and use the relationship "Flags : User"

5) Add the required fields.

Comment: if i create a user view -> then node fields like image, etc won't be available!

Comment: if you add the fag relatinship it will show...

Comment: Cannot select node fields now when i use user view!

Comment: did you add the node relationship? You should try adding the node:author relations ship as well.

Comment: There's no such an option in relationships.. all what i have is: Flags, Groups, Files (no node)

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please do these steps and let me know if you are getting the required result. Please note that it is indeed a node view and not a user view. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Works fine for D7 too, except `arguments` are now `contextual filters`.